# Getting ValueError: too many values to unpack for a GitHub package

Tags: python

I'm using a package from GitHub called `plot-trec_eval` to make a pdf with the precision-recall curve in it. I'm using a Google Colab notebook and, so far, I got this:

```py
! python /content/plot-trec_eval/plot_pr_curve.py -f prc_23.pdf /content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/23/23_N.txt /content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/23/r23_N.txt
```

And I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/plot-trec_eval/plot_pr_curve.py", line 47, in <module>
    process(args.files, args.output)
  File "/content/plot-trec_eval/plot_pr_curve.py", line 11, in process
    result_list = [EvaluationResult(f) for f in files]
  File "/content/plot-trec_eval/plot_pr_curve.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    result_list = [EvaluationResult(f) for f in files]
  File "/content/plot-trec_eval/eval_results.py", line 49, in __init__
    (field, query, value) = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

What seems to be the issue here? I'm not understanding. I've read the tracebacks and I still can't figure out the problem

Comment: Please, provide us with the files you're giving to the tool or (better) shortened versions of the files which give the same error. Also, it is good to give a link to the library/tool you're using, not just its name - at least because there are two repositories on Github with the name you mentioned

Comment: As @Kolay.Ne says, at the very least, can you please add the contents of your `r23_N.txt` file to your question.  My first guess is that that file is not formatted correctly, but that's just a wild guess given how little information you've provided.  What you should do to have the best shot at getting a useful answer to your question is provide a [mcve].

Comment: You guys were correct, the file isn't properly formatted. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for tech support with someone else's code (not shown to us), not a question about programming. The error indicates that the input data is not in the expected format. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation (such as the README for the Github project in question).

Comment: I understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here in the source code](https://github.com/hscells/plot-trec_eval/blob/6d3e24a4723de467ffb6a4ad1faac0a7ff8049b0/eval_results.py#L46-L49), `plot-trec_eval` expects each of your files (processed by [`process`](https://github.com/hscells/plot-trec_eval/blob/6d3e24a4723de467ffb6a4ad1faac0a7ff8049b0/plot_pr_curve.py#L10)) to be in a specific format: each line of them should consist of three "words" split by whitespaces (space / tab character / etc). The first of these words should represent something called "field" in the code, the second should describe a "query" and the last one should be a "value". You can find possible values for the "words" in the source too, but I guess you should know what you're doing when using the library.